# How to set input to it's min/max threshold if user input exceeds it

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input type "number" that has a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 99. I understand that if the user inputs a number above 99 or below 1 a prompt appears telling them to input a number 1-99. I want it so if a user inputs a number beyond the min/max it automatically adjusts itself to the min/max and doesn't prompt the user with this message.

Example: User puts 107, the number turns into 99. If the user puts -10, the number turns into 1.

I had a thought process of this:

if number is greater than 99 then turn number into 99

if number is less than 1 then turn number into 1

Although, I'm not sure how to write this in JavaScript (assuming I do have to use JS).

Comment: You can use min and max input properties https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking the value each time it changes

```js
var numInput = document.querySelector("input[type='number']");
numInput.onchange = function() {
  this.value = this.value > 99 ? 99 : this.value < 1 ? 1 : this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```